# C - Convert substring to int

Tags: c, type-conversion

At the moment I got this simple code in C to convert days, minutes and seconds to seconds only:

**EDITED** (I understood the problem with atoi, like this is corrected right?):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int getseconds(char * time)
{
    int seconds=0, i=0;
    char buffer[3];
    while (*time != '\0')
    {
        switch (*time)
        {
            case 'h': buffer[i]='\0';i=0;seconds=seconds+atoi(buffer)*3600;break;
            case 'm': buffer[i]='\0';i=0;seconds=seconds+atoi(buffer)*60;break;
            case 's': buffer[i]='\0';i=0;seconds=seconds+atoi(buffer);break;
            case ' ':break;
            default: buffer[i]=*time;i++;break;
        }
        time++;
    }
    return seconds;
}

int main()
{

    char *time = "12h  4m 58s";
    int seconds = getseconds(time);
    printf("%d",seconds);
    return 0;
}
```

This is working as I want, but there isn't another way to do it, without creating more variables (like C# where I just need to convert "inline". Does C only have functions that convert to variables and not to "inline")?

C# Example:

```
        string time = "12h 34m 58s";
        int seconds = int.Parse(time.Substring(0, 2)) * 3600 + int.Parse(time.Substring(4, 2)) * 60 + int.Parse(time.Substring(8, 2));
```

You can spot the number of lines difference I guess :).

Comment: Reread the question and deleted.

Comment: Unrelated note; `buffer` does not hold a string in this code (a string being a sequence of chars followed by a `\0`); if the garbage after it happens to be a digit, then atoi won't return what you expect.

Comment: @immibis buffer is just an "holder", since the specific "string" only have 2 numbers and I will not output it do I really need to terminate it with \0?

Comment: `atoi` takes a c-style string. A c-style string ends with a `\0`. So yes it is needed.

Comment: what do you mean by inline? In one line? If so, there's alot of type inference being done in C# that you CANNOT do in C (for obvious reasons). Short of the fact that C strings are not really strings but an array of chars terminated by a \0. time.Substring itself in C# probably has the same amount of code (or more) as your getseconds function.

Comment: @FrancoSolleza I mean by not placing the result to a variable, in C you normally place the input to a variable.

Comment: The C# code only works if the format is fixed.  What if there is only 1 digit before `h` or if the number of seconds is missing, or if the spacing varies?

Comment: @Exprove Just to clarify, do you mean that in the code `int seconds = int.Parse(time.Substring(0, 2)) * 3600 + int.Parse(time.Substring(4, 2)) * 60`, that the function call `int.Parse(time.Substring(0, 2))` is evaluated "inline" as in, within the line without assigning to a variable before using it in the rest of the expression?

Comment: @FrancoSolleza I am saying that C# functions return the input, while C functions return normally a condition (example, number of inputs correctly read, etc...).

Comment: *You can spot the number of lines difference I guess :).*  Yes we can!  It is an indication of your lack of experience, but here, you will learn how to improve ;-)

Comment: @chqrlie I know c# and lot of languages not my fault ;p, I am just entering in the C World, sorry If I am a noob yet :).

Comment: We have all been beginners, no need to be sorry, but you remark could be misconstrued as an indication of C# superiority... C aficionados are easily tripped.

Comment: Your attempt in C is not semantically equivalent to the C# code - the C# version does not attempt to validate the delimiters; neither does your accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `atoi()` or `strtol()` to do this job.  You do not need to extract substrings first, because these functions stop at the first character that cannot be converted.  You just need to take a varying view of where the string starts.  Thus, this code is fairly analogous to your C# example:

```
int getseconds(const char * time) {
    return atoi(time) * 3600 + atoi(time + 4) * 60 + atoi(time + 8);
}
```

Of course it will break on some malformed inputs, but so will the C# (albeit not all the *same* inputs).

Comment: Hmm that example is interesting, it is what I need. But just one question in C# you give a start and a end to substring, how atoi works? It simple sees that the next char isn't a number and return a number?

Comment: As I wrote in my answer `atoi()` stops when it reaches a character it cannot convert -- i.e. one that is not a base-10 digit.  `strtol()` does the same, but has some additional features, such as being able to handle bases other than 10, and giving you a means to find out where it left off parsing.

Comment: Simple and elegant, with the same shortcomings as the C# version. +1

Answer (score 2):

`sscanf()` with `"%n"` to detect the end of scanning is close but does use more variables.

```
int getseconds2(const char * time) {
   int h,m,s;
   int n = 0;
   sscanf(time, "%d h%d m%d s %n", &h,&m, &s, &n);
   if (n == 0 || time[n] != '\0') return -1;  // failure
   return h*3600 + m *60 + s;
}
```

The `"%n"` saves the count of characters scanned.  Since is used at the end of the format, testing to see if it is non-zero (the original value) and that `time` ended at the null character insures the integrity of the scan.

[@chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4593267/chqrlie) suggested a mis-match of C# functionality.

```
   // to match C#
   if (n == 0) return -1;  // failure
```

Comment: Unlike the C# example, your `sscanf` will fail if there are extra characters at the end of `time`.

Comment: @chqrlie  By removing the `|| time[n] != '\0'` code, then that matching functionality can be had.

Comment: Although this is a perfectly good way to scan a string such as the OP presented, he did ask for an approach that does not involve any temporaries.

Comment: @John Bollinger  Agreed this uses extra variables - yet they all exist with-in a function, so OP only needs to call `int seconds = getseconds2(time);`.  It comes down to the need for no extra variables versus the degree of needed error resiliency.

Comment: @chux, agreed.  Also, I stipulate that the requirement to avoid temporaries seems pretty arbitrary.

Comment: The solution works only if the string contains no following data, making it perhaps less flexible.  Using the converted field count return from sscanf rather than testing for nul might be better.

Comment: @Clifford Disagree.  The test for `n == 0` is similar to testing the `sscanf()` return value of `3` and has an advantage over the test  used [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34054885/2410359).  That one give the illusion that the `s` was parsed.  It returns 3 should the `s` exist in `time` or not..  The usage here of the test for `time[n] != '\0'`, which was commented on before, allows the OP to decide if trailing text is a good or bad thing.

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler solution is possible:

```
int getseconds( const char* time)
{
    int h, m, s = 0 ;
    char sdelim = 0 ;
    int check = sscanf( time, "%dh %dm %d%c", &h, &m, &s, &sdelim ) ;
    if( check == 3 && sdelim = 's' )
    {
        s = ((h * 60) + m) * 60 + s ;
    }

    return s ;
}
```

Comment: @chqrlie : Compiles just fine here - what error are you seeing?  Why should it return -1?  Neither of the OP's solutions do that  It is a matter of design rather then requirement.  Why remove the check variable? That is a matter of style.  I prefer to assign then test rather then call the function or put a complex expression in the if() because it makes debugging easier (in a symbolic debugger).

Comment: @chqrlie : Ah - chux fixed it that's why.  The fix makes the purpose of `check` clear.  The signature of the function was as defined in the original question, but if you insist.

Comment: It compiles thanks to @chux correction. -1 help distinguish parse failure from `00h 00m 00s`, but the OP does not seem to care.  You can further simplify by removing the `check` variable, but clarity has its virtues.

Comment: John Bollinger's version is unquestionably *much simpler*.

Comment: @chqrlie : removing `check` does not simplify it, it simply uses one fewer variable.  The optimiser will remove it in any case, and its presence makes debugging simpler as mentioned.  - I'll let it stand thanks.  Chux's version assumes that the string does not contain following text.  This version will work regardless of what follows.

Comment: I recognize that, but you will agree that John has a simpler one, just not semantically equivalent to yours, but much closer to the C# version.

Comment: @chqrlie : John's solution is indeed simpler and corresponds more closely to the OP's C# solution, but will return odd results for malformed strings.  This is more tolerant to the number of spaces, but does check the h/m/s delimiters.  It is certainly not semantically equivalent; for example it will produce a result from "1234567890" for example, even though that does not represent valid input.

Comment: That is true, you are both more tolerant and perform stricter checking. Note that you need chux approach to check for the `s` marker.  Incidentally, you will produce undefined behavior for `1234567890h 0m 0s`.  You get my vote at last for the effort.

Comment: @chqrlie : I concede the `s` delimiter point.  An exercise for the reader if it matters; suggest removing `s` from the format string check `time[n] == 's'`

Comment: Since the OP seems to prefer minimal to robust, I chose to "fix" the final delimiter check in any case.